# atom-typescript: set experimentalDecorators option

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I have begun using the Atom editor with the atom-typescript package on an existing project, and I am encountering this warning.

> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I tried adding `"experimentalDecorators": true` to the `compilerOptions` in `~/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/lib/tsconfig.json` but this did not help. What can I do to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Might be misunderstanding the question, but I'd assume you need to add it to your project's `tsconfig.json`, not the extension's?

Comment: I see; I had to add the file at the same level as `package.json`

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of projects in this codebase that I'll have to do that for...ugh. Go ahead and write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done :) Hopefully you'll just be able to copy and paste to get the rest of your projects set up...

Comment: Yeah it actually wasn't too bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to configure a particular project's TypeScript compiler settings, you need to create a `tsconfig.json` in the root directory of that project, like so:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

`tsc` and your editor plugin will both pick this up automatically, and the warning should disappear.