# Where is settings.json file in atom

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I have a very irritating problem with typescript. Looks like everyone uses VSCode for typescript by default except me. I am still stuck with Atom editor :(

The solution everyone suggests is by adding

```
{ "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib" }
```

to your `.vscode/settings.json`

But where do I do this in atom ?

**Update**: The error is

```
Set 'ExperimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning
```

Related issue : [Experimental decorators warning in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Did you try installing the https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript plugin for Atom?

Comment: The advice you post here is presumably for VSCode and won't be of any use in Atom. Install the package suggested by Sahan.

Comment: I have the plugin installed , have the option set in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's the problem with TypeScript in Atom, but to answer your original question:
If you are using Windows, you can find the configuration in `~/.atom` (where ~ is your user directory, e.g. `C:\Users\Username`)

Comment: There's no `settings.json`, this is a VSCode specific file. If you are looking for some configuration then you can find it in the folder I have specified. But I believe, the answer you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722805/atom-typescript-set-experimentaldecorators-option